# I cannot create a linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list, huffman-code

Basically for my assignment I need to implement code to do Huffman coding. For that I need to take input as a string and then create a list of characters and their frequencies. I need to create a new node when there is a new character. I have tried doing it in C with no result. When I try to print my linked list I simply cannot get any output. I believe I have failed in creating the list from the start.
My C code is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct node {
    char character;
    int frequency;
    struct node *next;
}head;

struct node *insert(int frequency, char character) {
    struct node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newNode->character = frequency;
    newNode->character = character;
    return newNode;
}

void create_freq_list(struct node *initial, int str_size, char str[]) {
    int i;
    struct node *temp;
    bool has_node;
    for (i = 0; i < str_size; i++) {
        temp = initial;
        has_node = false;
        while (temp->next != NULL) {
            if (temp->character == str[i]) {
                has_node = true;
                temp->frequency++;
            }
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        if (has_node == false) {
            while (temp->next != NULL) {
                temp = temp->next;
                if (temp->next == NULL) {
                    temp->next = insert(0, str[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    struct node *temp;
    char str[100];
    gets_s(str, 100);
    create_freq_list(&head, 100, str);

    temp = &head;
    while (temp->next != NULL) {
        printf("'%c' : %d", temp->character, temp->frequency);
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    getch();
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Does it need to be a linked list? For a frequency counter of a known number of elements, an array works great.

Comment: What debugger do you have access to?

Comment: Also, if you can use C++ lo and behold, [somebody already did that](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list). But yes, John is probably right, there are only so many chars, which is why an array indexed by char works well.

Comment: The main problem in your code, apart from assigning `character` to `frequency`, is that you never set `next` to null in `insert` (which is also misnamed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues in your code:

- Your handling of the `head` node is incorrect: `head` should be defined as a `node *` and you should pass its address to `create_freq_list()`.
- There is a typo in the `insert()` function: `newNode->character = frequency;`
- You should not iterate on characters of the string beyond the null terminator.
- The output loop is incorrect: it should iterate `while (head)`, not `while (head->next)`. As coded, the initial node is output but meaningless and the last node is ignored.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node {
    char character;
    int frequency;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *insert(int frequency, char character) {
    struct node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if (newNode != NULL) {
        newNode->frequency = frequency;
        newNode->character = character;
    }
    return newNode;
}

void create_freq_list(struct node **headp, const char str[]) {
    for (int i = 0; str[i]; i++) {
        struct node **tailp = *headp;
        struct node *temp;
        while ((temp = *tailp) != NULL) {
            if (temp->character == str[i]) {
                temp->frequency++;
                break;
            }
            tailp = &temp->next;
        }
        if (temp == NULL) {
            *tailp = insert(1, str[i]);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    struct node *head = NULL;
    char str[100];
    gets_s(str, 100);
    create_freq_list(&head, str);

    for (struct node *temp = head; temp != NULL; temp = temp->next) {
        printf("'%c': %d\n", temp->character, temp->frequency);
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Note that it is much simpler to use an array with 256 elements to compute the character frequencies.

Answer (score 1):

May I propose a variant, using macros of the excellent `<sys/queue.h>`
This is not a standard include, but every well packaged system should have it.
Well, it's probably less pedagogical than coding linked-list by hands, but it's more secure ;-)
Have a look at `man queue` (or `man LIST_INIT`) to see features.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <sys/queue.h>

typedef LIST_HEAD(listhead, entry) nodes_t;

typedef struct entry {
  char character;
  int frequency;
  LIST_ENTRY(entry) entries;
} node_t;


void insert(nodes_t *list, char character) {
  node_t *newNode = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
  if (newNode != NULL) {
    newNode->frequency = 1;
    newNode->character = character;
    LIST_INSERT_HEAD(list, newNode, entries);
  }
}

node_t *get_node(nodes_t *list, char character) {
  node_t *n;
  LIST_FOREACH(n, list, entries)
    if (n->character == character)
      return n;
  return NULL;
}

void create_freq_list(nodes_t *list, const char str[]) {
  node_t *n;
  for (int i = 0; str[i]; i++) {
    n = get_node(list, str[i]);
    if (n == NULL)
      insert(list, str[i]);
    else
      n->frequency++;
  }
}

void print_list(nodes_t *list) {
  node_t *n;
  LIST_FOREACH(n, list, entries)
    printf("'%c': %d\n", n->character, n->frequency);
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  nodes_t list;

  if (argc != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <string>\n", argv[0]);
    return -1;
  }
  
  LIST_INIT(&list);
  
  create_freq_list(&list, argv[1]);

  print_list(&list);
  
  return 0;
}
```